# change to swappiness on Debian 12 not sticking after a reboot

Tags: debian, swap

I have recently started upgrading my database servers from Debian 9 to Debian 12. However it seems that Debian 12 (and indeed 11) are prone to swapping very easily where Debian 9 never did.

So I want to change the value of `vm.swappiness` from its current value 5, down to 1 to see if that makes a difference.

Everywhere I look, suggests I simply need to add the entry `vm.swappiness = 1` to the end of the file `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

I have done this (and checked there is no other entry in it) and rebooted the server several times, but every time it comes back and tells me that the `vm.swappiness` is still 5.

I am assuming that there must therefore be somewhere else that this has been set, but googling for it hasn't helped, with everywhere saying it should be in `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

Can anyone suggest another location that this might be set please?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The file I was looking for turns out to be `/etc/sysctl.d/vm.swappiness.conf` (pretty obvious when you know where to look).

I located this by running `sysctl --system`. This showed that vm.swappiness was being set twice, once from the file I had changed, but once from elsewhere.

Looking at the list of files it output, it was quite obvious which one it was.

I removed the entry I had added, and changed the value in `/etc/sysctl.d/vm.swappiness.conf`, and following a re-boot it showed that the value had now changed to 1 as required.

Comment: Another way to look would be `grep -r swappiness /etc/sysctl*`.  (or `ack` is a nice `grep -r` alternative.)  If you'd forgotten about `/etc/sysctl.d`, tab-completion for `/etc/sysctl` will remind you :P

Comment: Side note: it looks like `/etc/sysctl.d/vm.swappiness.conf` is not managed by `dpkg`, it is a custom file that you added on your system. So other users won't have this file on their system.